# Laravel 5: Passing additional parameters to Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5 to build a website and have a few pages, whose content will be written in Blade (e.g. About, Terms and Conditions etc.) and others which would be pulled from database (General blog posts).

I'd like to write a single a controller and run a switch case to show specific view.

e.g.

`PagesController@showPage`:

```
public function showPage($page){
 switch ($page) {
    case 'about':
        $view = 'frontend.about';
        break;
    case 'terms':
        $view = 'frontend.terms';
        break;
    ...
    default:
        $view = 'frontend.home'
        break;
}

return view($view);
}
```

But how can I pass an additional parameter in `Routes.php`?

```
//Route to About page
Route::get('/about',['as'=>'about','uses'=>'PagesController@showPage']);

//Route to Terms
Route::get('/terms',['as'=>'terms','uses'=>'PagesController@showPage']);
```

Something like:

```
//Route to Terms
    Route::get('/terms',['as'=>'terms','uses'=>'PagesController@showPage'])->with(['page'=>'terms']);
```

Comment: Why is it not enough to have the complete `request` in your controller action via `public function showPage(Request $request)`. With that information you could implement your logic inside the controller and deliver different information into the view.

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy to pass variable in route. take a look at following code.

```
 Route::get('/terms/{page}',['as'=>'terms','uses'=>'PagesController@showPage']);
```

And you can access this value inside controller action as following example.

```
function showPage($page){
   echo $page;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your pages routes like this :

```
Route::('/pages/{slug}', 'PagesController@showPage') ;
```

And every time you create your routes just do this:

```
route('/pages', ['slug' => 'about']);
```

And from your controller get the slug as:

```
function showPage($slug) {
  switch($slug) :
    //write your cases
 }
```